# how to save html form data into sqlite database using python BaseHTTPServer

Tags: python, html, sqlite

I'm using python BaseHTTPServer,the code for it is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
from os import curdir, sep

PORT_NUMBER = 8080

#This class will handles any incoming request from
#the browser 
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        #Handler for the GET requests
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path=="/":
            self.path="/index_example2.html"

        try:
            #Check the file extension required and
            #set the right mime type

            sendReply = False
            if self.path.endswith(".html"):
                mimetype='text/html'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".jpg"):
                mimetype='image/jpg'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".gif"):
                mimetype='image/gif'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".js"):
                mimetype='application/javascript'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".css"):
                mimetype='text/css'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".png"):
                mimetype='image/png'
                sendReply = True

            if sendReply == True:
                #Open the static file requested and send it
                f = open(curdir + sep + self.path) 
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type',mimetype)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(f.read())
                f.close()
            return


        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)

try:
    #Create a web server and define the handler to manage the
    #incoming request
    server = HTTPServer(('192.168.1.129', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
    print 'Started httpserver on port ' , PORT_NUMBER

    #Wait forever for incoming htto requests
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print '^C received, shutting down the web server'
    server.socket.close()
```

using this im calling html code, which is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Template by html.am -->
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>BAT Box</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  
  body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 100%; 
   max-height: 100%; 
   font-family:Sans-serif;
   line-height: 1.5em;
  }
  
  #header {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px; 
   overflow: hidden; /* Disables scrollbars on the header frame. To enable scrollbars, change "hidden" to "scroll" */
   background: #BCCE98;
  }
  
  #nav {
   position: absolute; 
   top: 100px; 
   left: 0; 
   bottom: 0;
   width: 230px;
   overflow: auto; /* Scrollbars will appear on this frame only when there's enough content to require scrolling. To disable scrollbars, change to "hidden", or use "scroll" to enable permanent scrollbars */
   background: #DAE9BC;   
  }
  
  #logo {
   padding:10px;
  }
  
  main {
   position: fixed;
   top: 100px; /* Set this to the height of the header */
   left: 230px; 
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   overflow: auto; 
   background: #fff;
  }
  
  .innertube {
   margin: 15px; /* Provides padding for the content */
  }
  
  p {
   color: #555;
  }

  nav ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  
  nav ul a {
   color: darkgreen;
   text-decoration: none;
  }
    
  /*IE6 fix*/
  * html body{
   padding: 100px 0 0 230px; /* Set the first value to the height of the header and last value to the width of the nav */
  }
  
  * html main{ 
   height: 100%; 
   width: 100%; 
  }
  
  </style>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
   /* =============================
   This script generates sample text for the body content. 
   You can remove this script and any reference to it. 
    ============================= */
   
   function generateText(sentenceCount){
    for (var i=0; i<sentenceCount; i++)
    document.write(bodyText[Math.floor(Math.random()*7)]+" ")
   }
  </script> 
 
 </head>
 
 <body>  

  <header id="header">
   <div id="logo">
   <img src='image/logo.png' align="right" style="width:75px;height:50px;">
    <h1>CoolLogo</h1>
   </div>
  </header>
    
  <main>
   <div class="innertube">
    <fieldset style="width:400px; height: 150px; color:0FF;padding:2px;">
    
    <table style="background-color:#FFFFE0;">
     <form method="POST" action="/send">
     <tr>
      <td>IP Address</td><td><input type="text"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Net Mask</td><td><input type="text"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Gateway</td><td><input type="text"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>MAC Address</td><td><input type="text"/></td>
     </tr>
     
    </table>
    
</fieldset>
      
     <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" margin-right: 100px;/>

     <input type="submit" value="Reset"/>
    </div>
   </div>

  </main>

  <nav id="nav">
   <div class="innertube">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    
     <form action="/login" method="POST">
    <ul>
     <label>Insert your name: </label><input type="text" name="your_name"/>
     <li><a href="index_example2.html">IP</a></li>
     <li><a href="index_example3.html">FSQ</a></li>
     <li><a href="index_example4.html">Server&FTP IP</a></li>
     <li><a href="index_example2.html">4</a></li>
     <li><a href="index_example2.html">5</a></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
   </div>
  </nav> 
 </body>
</html>

 <!--meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"-->
```

Answer (score 0):

- Connect to your database using [sqlite3.connect()](https://kite.com/python/docs/sqlite3.connect) method
- Run sql `CREATE TABLE` (see here for syntax, use `IF NOT EXISTS` to handle already exists cases)
- Define post method handler
- Parse form data using [parse_qs()](https://kite.com/python/docs/urlparse.parse_qs) for that
- Execute SQL INSERT statement with `name` field from form.

Comment: Browser does the sending, you will need to add `do_POST()` method to your `myHandler` class